# Spring Data JPA Hibernate One-to-One doesn't create parent FK in child

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I have parent entity 'Book' with child entity field 'cover' (just for simpler examle):

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Cover cover;
}

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "cover")
public class Cover {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Book book;
}
```

DDL for tables:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKS(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE COVER(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, CONTENT VARCHAR(255), BOOK_ID INT);
ALTER TABLE COVER ADD FOREIGN KEY (BOOK_ID) REFERENCES BOOKS(ID);
```

So, when I call bookRepository.save(book) I get created 1 new line in 'books' table and 1 new line in 'cover' table. But field 'BOOK_ID' in 'cover' table is EMPTY!

How can I fix it?

UPD for Faeemazaz Bhanej
I dont have any special in controller:

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/book")
public Book saveBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
    return service.saveBook(book);
}
```

Service:

```
public Book saveBook(Book book) {
    return repository.save(book);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me your code of `bookRepository.save(book)`

Comment: it's jpa repository, so there no my code in save(book)

Comment: I am not talking about `Repository` method. I wanna see your `post` method in `Controller`

Comment: added to question, but there is nothing special